# Кофе - он или оно?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, род

Все-таки, как правильно: кофе - это он или оно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В разговорной речи допустимы оба варианта. Однако если говорить об исключительно правильной литературной речи (особенно, письменной), то кофе все-таки мужского рода.

Comment: Говорят, тенденция такова, что скоро средний род для кофе придется признать столь же корректным как и мужской.